# I want to store NSString data in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to store data in `NSMutableDictionary`. continue change `NSString` value I want to store this value in `NSMutableDictionary`, but when second time store value in `NSMutableDictionary` then clear old value so how to store one by one value in `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
    NSString *tempitemname = itemselectedlbl.text;
    NSString *temprate = ratelbl.text;
    NSString *tempquant = quantitylbl.text;
    NSString *temptotal = totallbl.text;
    NSString *temptotalbill = totalbilllbl.text;

    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setValue:tempitemname forKey:@"itemname"];
    [dict setValue:temprate forKey:@"rate"];
    [dict setValue:tempquant forKey:@"quantity"];
    [dict setValue:temptotal forKey:@"total"];
    [dict setValue:temptotalbill forKey:@"totalbill"];
```

Continue change all labels value I want store these values in `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Of course they clear the old value - an `NSDictionary` - any dictionary/hash/object is a key-value mapping - one key to one value. What do you want to accomplish? Maybe you want to store an `NSMutableArray` of strings for each key?

Comment: Please check the stack overflow for similar questions before you ask anything. These are very basic questions and a lot of questions and answers are already available regarding this.

Comment: Sorry to say this but don't ask such type of questions. First search about the question you will get hundreds of answers related to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary doesn't allow duplicate key to store inside them. So when you set the values second time then it overwrites the data if there is already a key available inside the dictionary. So you can't store again and again and still expect it to hold all the data.